# How to style other divs differently on hover of a particular div?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have my html like this

```
<div class="add-lineitem-block whiteBgRow">
  <div class="add-link">
    <span class="add-icn">
      <img class="add-icn-img" title="Add Lineitem" src="/newlayout/images/add-icn.png" alt="" style="display: none;">
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div class="lineitem-icn-nav" style="">
    <span class="mediamath-icn serverjs" ref="MEDIAMATH">
      <img id="mediamath_icon" title="Add a Mediamath Lineitem" src="/newlayout/images/mediamath-icn.png" alt="">    
    </span>
    <span class="dfp-icn serverjs" ref="DFP">
      <img id="dfp_icon" title="Add a DFP Lineitem" src="/newlayout/images/dfp-icn.png" alt="">    
    </span>
    <span class="fb-icn serverjs" ref="FB">
      <img id="facebook_icon" title="Add a Facebook Lineitem" src="/newlayout/images/fb-icn.png" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to increase the size of `#dfp_icon` and decrease the size of `#mediamath_icon` and `#facebook_icon` when hovered on `#dfp_icon`.

Here is my CSS

```
#facebook_icon{ height: 80px; }

#mediamath_icon{ height: 80px; }

#dfp_icon{ height: 80px; }

#dfp_icon:hover{height: 100px;}
```

I tried this `+` and `~` operators but that can apply only the same style. Is it possible to style `#mediamath_icon` and `facebook_icon` differently on hovering `#dfp_icon`?

Comment: You can not achieve this by CSS, jQuery highly recommended if you're able to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `#facebook_icon` is not appearing, although it works in my machine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dfp_icon').hover(function() {
    $('#mediamath_icon').css('width', '40px');
    $('#mediamath_icon').css('height', '40px');
    $('#facebook_icon').css('width', '40px');
    $('#facebook_icon').css('height', '40px');
    $(this).css('width',
      '120px');
    $(this).css('height', '120px');
  }, function() {
    $('#mediamath_icon').css('width', '80px');
    $('#mediamath_icon').css('height', '80px');
    $('#facebook_icon').css('width', '80px');
    $('#facebook_icon').css('height', '80px');
    $(this).css('width', '80px');
    $(this).css('height', '80px');
  });
});
```

```css
#mediamath_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#dfp_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#facebook_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="mediamath_icon">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="dfp_icon">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="facebook_icon">
</div>
```

Or if you want for all icons, try this version

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icons').hover(function() {
    $('.icons').css('width', '40px');
    $('.icons').css('height', '40px');
    $(this).css('width', '120px');
    $(this).css('height', '120px');
  }, function() {
    $('.icons').css('width', '80px');
    $('.icons').css('height', '80px');
    $(this).css('width', '80px');
    $(this).css('height', '80px');
  });
});
```

```css
#mediamath_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#dfp_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#facebook_icon {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="mediamath_icon" class="icons">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="dfp_icon" class="icons">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="facebook_icon" class="icons">
</div>
```

Comment: If the downvote is about the missing "icon", I can't really do much about it if it is not appearing in the snippet. It does appear in my machine

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascript `onmouseover` then `toggleclass` :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV1");

  element.onmouseover = function() {
    element.classList.toggle("bigger-size");
  };

}

myFunction();
```

```css
.standerd-size {
  height: 20px;
}

.bigger-size {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV1" class="standerd-size">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div id="myDIV2">
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to change color and background color on hover and also changed width and height.

```css
.two:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.one:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"> Hello</div>
<div class="two"> Hello Again</div>
```

Comment: It's not what the op asked.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt please stop editing posts to add unnecessary space into the code. You are not improving their readibility or quality by doing so, and you are missing out on other aspects of the post that should be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it! using a simple jQuery.

```
$(function() {
      $('#dfp_icon').hover(function() {
        $('#mediamath_icon').css('height', '40px');
        $('#facebook_icon').css('height', '40px');
      }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the height
        $('#mediamath_icon').css('height', '80px');
        $('#facebook_icon').css('height', '80px');
      });
    });
```

Comment: This only works for the specific icon, I am sure the op would like to get the same effect when hovering the Facebook icon for example, and for that, this is way too complicated way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#dfp-icon:hover{height:100px;}
#dfp-icon:hover #mediamath-icn{height:70px;}
#dfp-icon:hover #fb-icn{height:70px;}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.